# rescue_from handlers inside two different modules

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I try to create facade module, for module that do some generic exceptions handling, with additional logic.

For examle, first module:

```rb
module GenericErrorHandler
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    rescue_from Sequel::NoMatchingRow do |e|
      render json: {code: 404, error: e}
    end

    rescue_from StandardError do |e|
      render json: {code: 500, error: e}
    end
  end
end
```

And second module with logging:

```rb
module ErrorLogger
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  include GenericErrorHandler
  
  included do
    rescue_from StandardError do |e|
      puts "logged error #{e.to_s}"
      raise
    end
  end
end
```

When I include `ErrorLogger` in class that raises `StandardException`, only handler from `ErrorLogger` was called. But I expect, that handler from `GenericErrorHandler` must be called too because of `raise` in `ErrorLogger` handler. Is this possible to achieve such behavior? (looks like `rescue_from` from other module rewrites handlers after module inclusion)

Answer (score 1):

Do you consider using methods instead of blocks?

```rb
module GenericErrorHandler
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def handle_standard_error(e)
    render json: {code: 500, error: e}
  end

  included do
    rescue_from Sequel::NoMatchingRow do |e|
      render json: {code: 404, error: e}
    end

    rescue_from StandardError, with: :handle_standard_error
  end
end

module ErrorLogger
  include GenericErrorHandler
  
  def handle_standard_error(e)
    puts "logged error #{e.to_s}"
    super
  end
end
```